# How to shuffle rows in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table with 2 columns : id (Primary Key) and name. Now this table is order by name , but I want to shuffle all rows and change id to a random number. How could I do this ?

Is it possible to use update command and set id to a random unique number like this ?

```
UPDATE mytable SET id = **GENERATE UNIQUE NUMBER**
```

P.S. This table is independence. Id is not a foreign key to another table.

[image]

Comment: Do you really need to change ID's or just get elements in random order? `1, 2, 3, 4` is also random order...

Comment: I really need to change ID, thank you.

Comment: `PK`'s should never be changedn as this can lead to bad relations between existing data

Comment: Yes, it is possible(but I would not advise it) **[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=45717c83c30c94127d03e8d2a70fe9cd)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you do not update primary key field in your table instead simply you can get them in random order by using the following query.

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY RAND();
```

or you can add another column in which you can add random values. like this

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD COLUMN rand_id int;

UPDATE MYTABLE SET 
RAND_ID = SELECT RAND()*((SELECT MAX(ID) FROM mytabl)-1)+1;
```

Comment: This is not really a "shuffle" because the `rand_id` can have the same value in different rows.  Perhaps that is what the the OP really wants (the answer is accepted), but the use of the word "shuffle" and the sample data suggest otherwise.

Comment: Actually didn't understand what you mean.  will surely appreciate if you could change answer to make it right.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is right, I got same value in rand_id so, this is not valid Answer, and some values from ID is not present in rand_id . For ex. I have 900 Record, after applied this answer, while I try to get record `where rand_id = 1` then got 1 record but while I tried `rand_id=5` that returns 2 records there are so many duplicates happpeneds

Comment: @ShurvirMori . . . Perhaps you should ask a question about your specific problem.

Comment: My question is same, but i tried this solution but not working solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the rows in a random order, grab the required number of rows and then use PHP's shuffle function on the array of rows returned. There can be quite a performance penalty with using ORDER BY RAND() in a query, depending on how many records there are.

Don't change any IDs as you'll break/bugger up any relationships between the records in this table and any related tables.